# get state (Checked or UnChecked) of Checkedit in Ribbon Bar (DevExpress) C#

Tags: c#, checkbox, devexpress

How do i get value from Checkedit (CheckBox) in RibbonBar DevExpress C#

i spent hours to surf google , I found little bit regarding this context but this is in VB , i need in C#

This is what i found in VB 
Please help me 
Thanks

```
` Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

`` End Sub

Private Sub repositoryItemCheckEdit1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles repositoryItemCheckEdit1.CheckedChanged
    Dim edit As CheckEdit = TryCast(sender, CheckEdit)
    XtraMessageBox.Show(edit.Checked.ToString())
End Sub

Private Sub repositoryItemCheckEdit1_EditValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles repositoryItemCheckEdit1.EditValueChanged

End Sub` ``

Answer (score 0):

Using the EditValueChanged property I was able to solve this.

Select the item -> Events -> Double click EditValueChanged and add the code below:[image: Ribbon Bar Events]

```
    bool isChecked = false;

    private void barEditItem1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (barEditItem1.EditValue.ToString() == "False")
        {
           isChecked = false;
        }
        else
        {
           isChecked = true;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you gave me the answer 
actually i want to get the value of Checkedit state in that lies in Ribbon bar 
how may i achieve it 
as you mentioned to double click the checkedit in ribbon but as soon as i double clicked it genereates the following code  
but
still havent get my solution 


`

  private void barEditItem4_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {

        }`

Comment: i did but it wont work for me as i double click the checkedit(CheckBox) in ribbon it generates the following code as mentioned earlier but according to you it generates **barEditItem1_EditValueChanged "  but for me it generates 
** barEditItem4_ItemClick  ** here is the code below  
.
.
.
  

{
       private void barEditItem4_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {

        }

}


Please take a look or this pic it might help you to depecit what i am trying to achieve or convey 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByUu8YvaGsOtYWhUNkFEc1diS0E

Comment: @Jon See the updated answer to access the event, alternatively you can paste the whole code block and replace barEditItem1 with barEditItem4.